# How to prove the intersection of these normal lines to a smooth curve $\alpha\in C^\infty$ converges to $\alpha(s_0)+\frac{1}{k(s_0)}N(s_0)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

$\alpha:I\to \Bbb R^2$ is a curve $\alpha\in C^\infty$ with natural parametrization and $s_0\in I$ with curvature $k(s_0)\neq 0$.

A normal line $r$ in $s\in I$ is given by $\alpha(s)+\lambda N(s)$, and the normal line $r_0$ in $s_0$ is given by $\alpha(s_0)+\mu N(s_0)$. Intersections variating $s\in I$ are given by
$\alpha(s)+\lambda(s) N(s)=\alpha(s_0)+\mu(s) N(s_0)$, where $N$ is the normal vector.

Applying dot product with tangent vector $T(s)$ and obtaining $\mu(s)$ we have:

$<\alpha(s)-\alpha(s_0),T(s))>=\mu(s)<N(s_0),T(s)>$

But in this step I don't know how to clear $\mu(s)$, I'd have to divide by $<N(s_0),T(s)>$ and the rest would be easy for applying limits $s\to s_0$. But that dot product can be zero, so I think a subinterval $J\subset I$ exists where $<N(s_0),T(s)>\neq 0$ if $s\neq s_0$ and I can do the limit, but I don't know how to confirm such a subinterval exists because I'm thinking of curves where for every interval $(s_0-\varepsilon,s_0+\varepsilon)$ exists $s_1$ in it such that $<N(s_0),T(s_1)>=0$, I don't know whether that has sense since we're considerating  $\alpha\in C^\infty$ with $k(s_0)\neq 0$.

I imagine curves similar to the image.[image] So, if this method of proof is valid, I have to guarantee a subinterval with no zeros in that dot product exists to clear $\mu(s)$ and applying limits.

Comment: Are you sure you would not rather dot with $N(s_0)$?

Comment: I tried it because I thought $\mu(s)$ would be without any element multiplying and easier to clear. But I didn't obtain anything interesting applying limits. Even derivating the dot product: $<(1-\lambda(s)k(s)T(s),N(s_0))>+\lambda'(s)<N(s),N(s_0)>=r'(s)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to retain the full vector equation
$$\alpha(s)+\lambda(s)N(s) = \alpha(s_0)+\mu(s)N(s_0),$$
and think of this as a system of linear equations for $\lambda,\mu$, i.e.,
$$\lambda(s)N(s) - \mu(s)N(s_0) = -(\alpha(s)- \alpha(s_0)).$$

By Cramer's rule, we have
$$\mu(s) = \frac{\left|\begin{matrix} N(s) & \alpha(s)-\alpha(s_0)\end{matrix}\right|}{\left|\begin{matrix} N(s) & N(s_0)\end{matrix}\right|}.$$
Letting $\Delta s = s-s_0$, now we use the Frenet equations to get
$$\mu(s) = \frac{\left|\begin{matrix} N(s) & T(s_0)\Delta s\end{matrix}\right|}{\left|\begin{matrix} -\kappa(s_0)T(s_0)\Delta s & N(s_0)\end{matrix}\right|},$$
ignoring terms that are $o(\Delta s)$. Since $N(s)=N(s_0)+O(\Delta s)$, this gives us
$$\lim_{\Delta s\to 0} \mu(s) = \frac1{\kappa(s_0)},$$
as required.